# How to perform loop in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, sum

For Example:

**Table:** test

```
+--+-----+-----+
|id|name |value|
+--+-----+-----+
|1 |test1|5    |
+--+-----+-----+
|2 |test2|3    |
+--+-----+-----+
|3 |test3|7    |
+--+-----+-----+
|4 |test4|9    |
+--+-----+-----+
```

I want to add all the values from "*test*" table by using sql query

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;
 CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE add INT DEFAULT 0;
 test_loop : LOOP
 SELECT value;
 SET add = add +1;      
 END LOOP; 
 END;
```

Desired output is: 24

Comment: use an aggregate  Something like `Select sum(value) from Test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(a.value)
FROM test a
```

**OR**

```
SELECT (@value:=@value+a.value) val
FROM test a, (SELECT @value) b
ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need loop, but you can use SUM operator:

```
   SELECT sum(`value`) FROM `test`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate function for that like sum.

For example

```
Select sum(value) from test
```